# What to choose when importing p12 into keychain

Tags: ios, authentication, system, keychain, pem

System or Login? Which one is supposed to be?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All of my iOS certificates are under "login" so I would choose "login".

You choose "login" because they are certificates specific to your login account.